# Program, that creates triangle and square

Tags: python, shapes

I've started learning programming and I need to create program, where user can enter amount of rows wanted and then program has to print two different shapes according to the info given by user. Shapes have to be like

> Blockquote

```
                         # # # # #        *
                         #       #        * *
                         #       #  AND   * * *
                         #       #        * * * *
                         # # # # #        * * * * *
```

I managed to do the triangle, but I can't figure out, how to create square that is empty inside. I have only done it filled inside.
Can anyone help me to modify my code?

```
    userInput = input("Enter amount of row's wanted: ")
def shape(userInput, drawCharacter):
    n = 0
    while n < int(userInput):
        n += 1
        if drawCharacter == "*":
            print(n*drawCharacter.rjust(3))
        elif drawCharacter == "#":
            print(int(userInput)*drawCharacter.rjust(3))

shape(userInput, "*")

print("|__________________|\n")

shape(userInput, "#")
```

Comment: I suggest that you step away from the computer. Get a pen and paper and write **in words** the steps that you can take to create the square. Look for patterns in how it is build. What are the basic building blocks?

Comment: Hi Jung Carl and welcome to stackoverflow.  I can see that you are struggling with a beginner (homework?) problem, and we don't just want to do the work for you, because... that would defeat the joy of learning.  I'll leave you with a hint : what kind of test can you devise to answer the question "is this the first or last column?", and see where that takes you.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a homework question

Answer (score 1):

A method using `numpy` array to avoid loops when generating the matrix:

```
import numpy

n = 5 # or userinput, has to be >= 2
mat = np.full((n,n), '#') # a matrix of #s
mat[1:-1, 1:-1] = np.full((n-2, n-2), ' ') # make the center of the matrix ' '
print('\n'.join([' '.join(e) for e in mat]))
```

result:

```
# # # # #
#       #
#       #
#       #
# # # # #
```

Answer (score 0):

Your box consists of basically following parts:

1. Top and bottom rows: `print (width * '#')`
2. And center rows: `print ('#{}#'.format(' ' * (width - 2)))`

And as an exercise you just need to figure out the loop.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first encounter with programming(any language), what I would recommend you to do is to try to implement this problem with ***nested for loops*** (which will simulate a ***2d-array***, or basically a ***matrix***), try to figure out what index-es of the matrix not to print out and print out only the edges.
By doing this approach you will get a much better in-depth understanding of the problem that this task presents and how to solve it. Good luck!